# Class casting dynamically in swift

Tags: swift, casting

I am trying to dyanmically cast to a class in Swift. Is this possible? Here is the code I am trying to use:

```
let stringClass: AnyClass = NSString.self
let anyObject: AnyObject = "foo"
let string = anyObject as! stringClass
```

The code fails to compile at the cast. Is this possible and if so, why is the right syntax?

#### Real use case

Here is the real issue. I am attempting to refactor this code:

```
switch (value) {
    case "valueOne":
        viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "foo") as! FirstViewController
    case "valueTwo":
        viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "bar") as! SecondViewController
    default:
        return nil
}
```

into:

```
let controllersDictionary: [String: (String, UIViewController.Type)] = [
    "valueOne" : ("bar", FirstViewController.self),
    "valueTwo" : ("foo", SecondViewController.self)
]
let tuple = controllersDictionary[value]!
let identifier = tuple.0
let cast = tuple.1
let viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: identifier) as! cast
```

Comment: Does dynamic casting even make sense in a statically typed system?

Comment: Yes! In this case, we were aiming to cast to different types under specific conditions (think of instantiating multiple different ViewControllers from a storyboard)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27591438/3141234

Comment: This problem is usually solved using associated types or generics.

Comment: Posted a solution using protocols, curious if it will work for your needs

Comment: "think of instantiating multiple different ViewControllers from a storyboard" I'm having a failure of imagination. Can you show _that_ code so that we can see what the practical problem _really_ is?

Comment: @matt updated with my real problem

Comment: @AlexCurran I still don't see why you need the cast at that moment. Why isn't the identifier sufficient? The `viewController` will in fact be an instance of the right view controller subclass, automatically, so what's the cast for?

Comment: That's a good point... this is a piece of legacy code so I maybe haven't captured all the context. I'll have a look again on Monday

Comment: If you're not having to actually do anything more specific than just using UIViewController you don't need to cast it to the subclass at all

Answer (score 7):

I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to achieve, but here's a working version of your example:

```
func cast<T>(value: Any, to type: T) -> T? {
    return castedValue as? T
}

let inputValue: Any = "this is a test"
let inputType = String.self()
let casted = cast(value: inputValue, to: inputType)

print(casted)
```

Comment: The problem with this is that it works with the static type of `inputType` (therefore you could simply do the conditional cast directly) – if you write `let inputType : Any = Int()`, then the `cast` function will still succeed. Although as you correctly say in your above (and below) comment, this kind of conversion doesn't really make too much sense in a statically typed system anyway.

Comment: @Hamish Yep. None of this makes sense :p

Comment: Hmm OK. So in terms of class structure, what class is s inputType?

Comment: And it does make sense, just because you have static types doesn't mean you always know the type! My example is possible in Java and I would like to understand if it is possible in Swift, and if not, why.

Comment: You can option click an identifier to see more information about it, including its (infered or explicit) type

Comment: @AlexCurran I'm curious to see your Java implementation. The whole point of static typing is that types are known at compile time, which allows for provable type checking. If you're casting to a type that isn't known statically, then you can't do any such things at compile time.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not seeing what the cast at this point is for. You can write:

```
let controllersDictionary: [String: String] = [
    "valueOne" : "bar",
    "valueTwo" : "foo"
]
let identifier = controllersDictionary[value]!
let viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: identifier)
```

The cast does nothing for you in the code that you have shown. `viewController` is typed as UIViewController, but it is the correct underlying view controller subclass thanks to polymorphism; whatever the class is in the storyboard, that's the class of this instance.

The only time you need to cast down is when you have to message an instance with a message belonging only to the subclass, and you have not shown any such need at this point in your code.

Answer (score 1):

While there are/will be ways to make this kind of thing work, the Swifty solution (IMO) is to have your desired classes adhere to a protocol that defines the shared behavior you're trying to use, or simply use a super class they have in common

This allows the dynamism requried (in most cases at least) while still allowing the compile-time checks that prevent run time errors.

For your example,

```
protocol Stringable {
    func toString() -> String
}

extension String: Stringable {
    func toString() -> String {
        return self
    }
}

let thing = "foo"
let anything: Any = thing
let test: String? = (anything as? Stringable)?.toString()
```

Note that this requires "Any" rather than "AnyObject" since you need to cast to a protocol

Since you mentioned ViewControllers, I thought this might help:

```
static func createViewController<T: UIViewController>(storyboard: String, scene: String) -> T? {
    return  UIStoryboard(name: storyboard, bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(scene) as? T
}
```

Comment: The storyboard example you gave is very close to what I want! This would work well. I was just seeing if there is a way of doing in as I wanted. But thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

The `x as! Y.Type` syntax only works when Y is explicitly stated.

So, the compiler wants `x as! NSString`. The compiler crash is a bug, I suggest that you file a report.

And just think about it for a second, how would that even help you? `stringClass` is of type `AnyClass`, and you're **force** casting an `AnyObject` which *already* conforms to `AnyClass`. You should cast when you have a static type in mind, because casting doesn't really make any sense otherwise.

If you want to check, however, whether your object's class is a *subclass* of a particular type, you'd use:

`x is Y.Type`

Comment: "You should cast when you have a static type in mind, because casting doesn't really make any sense otherwise." exactly. If the rest of the static type system doesn't know about your dynamic type, then what good would it be?

Comment: Please see my updated question with the real example to see if it is clearer what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: @AlexanderMomchliov please stop implying my question is a "bad" question, that is not really in the community spirit. I'm sorry if it wasn't clear enough for you

Comment: @AlexCurran My apologies, if it came off that way, but I don't mean to come off like that at all. I'm merely suggesting that the solution you have in mind might not be a viable one in a static language to solve the problem you have. If you give us more details about the big picture, we can suggest a more appropriate solution

Comment: no problem,thanks for the reply. I've updated my question with the exact use case now :)

Answer (score 0):

Its possible so long as you can provide "a hint" to the compiler about the type of... `T`.  So in the example below one must use `: String?`.

```
func cast<T>(_ value: Any) -> T? {
    return value as? T
}

let inputValue: Any = "this is a test"
let casted: String? = cast(inputValue) 
print(casted) // Optional("this is a test")
print(type(of: casted)) // Optional<String>
```

Why Swift doesn't just allow us to `let casted = cast<String>(inputValue)` I'll never know.

---

One annoying scenerio is when your func has no return value.  Then its not always  straightford to provide the necessary "hint".  Lets look at this example...

```
func asyncCast<T>(_ value: Any, completion: (T?) -> Void) {
    completion(value as? T)
}
```

The following client code DOES NOT COMPILE. It gives a "Generic parameter 'T' could not be inferred" error.

```
let inputValue: Any = "this is a test"
asyncCast(inputValue) { casted in
    print(casted) 
    print(type(of: casted))
}
```

But you *can* solve this by providing a "hint" to compiler as follows:

```
asyncCast(inputValue) { (casted: String?) in
    print(casted) // Optional("this is a test")
    print(type(of: casted)) // Optional<String>
}
```