# Type cast an instance of a class

Tags: ios, swift

Let's say I have two classes: `FirstViewController` and `SecondViewController`.

`self.tabBarController?.viewControllers![0]` can be an instance from either of those two.

This one is no problem:

```
let firstVC =  self.tabBarController?.viewControllers![0] as! FirstViewController
```

But this one gives error "classOfVC is not a type":

```
    let aVC = self.tabBarController?.viewControllers![0]        
    let classOfVC = object_getClass(aVC)       
    let myVC = aVC as! classOfVC
```

Any suggestions?

Edit:  I do not want to use isKindOfClass because I am trying to avoid using if ... else if... and since there are more than two classes envolved.

Comment: The meta-type `classOfVC` isn't known until runtime, but the compiler needs a static type for `myVC`, which is why what you're trying to do doesn't make that much sense. What's the actual problem that you're trying to solve? This Q&A may be relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38792315/class-casting-dynamically-in-swift

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type cast operator (`as?` or `as!`) is compile time operator. Type of any variable in Swift can't be dynamic as you intend to achieve with your cast.

You can't easily avoid `if let`, `guard` etc. In your your case you can do an explicit cast (`as!`), if you know that view controller at particular index never changes. But it is not recommended approach, usually you should tend to avoid using explicit casting.

Comment: It made sense now.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `isKindOfClass` to check the object of which class

```
let aVC = self.tabBarController?.viewControllers![0]   
if avc.isKindOfClass(FirstViewController) {
    //type of first ViewController
}
else if avc.isKindOfClass(SecondViewController) {
    //type of second ViewController
}
```

Comment: I am trying to avoid using if ... else if ...  See my Edit.

Comment: I ended up using isKindOfclass.