# Trying to automate type casting

Tags: swift

The problem is that func type(of:) causes an error using for casting Any variable, despite it returns Int and should cast Any to Int

```
func cast<T>(_ value: Any, to type: T.Type) -> T { value as! T }

var item: Any = 5
cast(item, to: type(of: item)) // causes an error instead of returning Int
```

Is there a way to do this somehow? Can using ObjC help here?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please see [ask] and take the [tour]. Your post needs improvement. Start by making your title a clear, specific question.

Comment: Casting with the a variable or function just fundamentally doesn't make sense. When you cast a value, you're making an assertion to the compiler that the type of the value at runtime will be some statically known type. The whole point is for it to be **statically** known, so that this information can be used in type-checking. For a moment, suppose this was possible, and consider the next line of your example. When I type `casted.`, what methods should the IDE offer to auto-complete? It doesn't know anything about the type of `casted` beyond it being "the type of `item`", which it doesn't know.

Comment: The new version of your question is also impossible for the same reasons as the previous.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect there's a fundamental misunderstanding here of what types are. I call this the "what's the next line?" problem. Consider:

```
func f<T>(value: Any, type: T) {
    let casted = value as! type
    // ... ok, now what?
}
```

This is invalid, but let's say it were allowed. What would you **do** with `casted` at this point? What would the next line of code look like? What method could you call without knowing the type? What function could you pass it to that took anything more restrictive than Any? Its type is `type`, sure, but that doesn't buy you anything. It's no different than being Any because you don't know anything about its shape. That's what types tell you: what can be done to and with the value.

Much of the issue probably comes from your premise: "If we need to cast type of Any...." You should ask why you have Any in the first place. If you think you can use `as!` safely, you must know the type of the value. Why is Any involved? Go back to that step, redesign to get rid of the Any, and many type problems will evaporate.

To the second half of your question, consider just the signature:

```
func function<T>() -> T
```

This says the caller may ask for any type in existence, and this function will return one. Absolutely anything. It can be an internal Apple type that exposes no public inits. It could be a random type in a custom module you've never heard of. It could be an uninhabited type (such as [Never](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/Swift/Never)) that literally **cannot** be constructed because there are intentionally no values of that type. This function promises that it will return one nonetheless. There is no way to implement this function, even in theory, other than calling `fatalError()` and crashing.

What you almost certainly mean is that you want to return one of some fixed list of types. You don't mean Any (you're not going to return a CBPeripheral for example). Most people mean "JSON-like types, Stings, Numbers, Arrays, that kind of thing." If so, then that's a protocol.

A really great example of this pattern is [RangeReplaceableCollection](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/rangereplaceablecollection#). It requires an `init()` method that returns an empty collection. The semantics are important here. [Protocols are not just bags of syntax.](https://oleb.net/blog/2016/12/protocols-have-semantics/) With RRC, you can write meaningful algorithms in the way you're describing:

```
func function<T: RangeReplaceableCollection>() -> T {
    var item: T = T()
    return item
}
```

---

You haven't given an actual example of what you're trying to do with `casted`, so I'm going to guess at your use case and you can let me know if this is the wrong road and you can explain the actual problem you mean. Perhaps you currently have something like:

```
func addOne(value: Any) -> Int {
    let intValue = value as! Int
    return intValue + 1
}

addOne(value: 4)
```

And you would like to avoid having to write `as! Int` and just make it be "whatever the runtime type is." So you write:

```
func addOne(value: Any) -> Int {
    let intValue = value as! type(of: value)
    return intValue + 1
}
```

But that can't work. What do you want to happen if I call `addOne(value: "x")`? In that case the `as!` would succeed (it can't fail since it's its own type). But what would `+` do? What if I passed a CBPeripheral or UIViewController? This is the whole problem Swift types are there to help us avoid. If this could work in Swift, then there wouldn't even be a need for the `as!`. You could just use Any and it'd be figured out at runtime and do "something" (maybe crash) like in JavaScript.

Or perhaps you're trying to write something to handle "any number type" and are trying to write it this way:

```
func addOne(value: Any) -> type(of: value) {
    let intValue = value as type(of: value)
    return intValue + 1
}
```

But it's not working. And that's because Any is the wrong type here. Any is almost always the wrong type. Instead, you want generics and protocols, which can handle this directly and safely:

```
func addOne<Value>(value: Value) -> Value
where Value: AdditiveArithmetic & ExpressibleByIntegerLiteral {
    return value + 1
}
```

Then there's no need for casting. If you're finding yourself calling `as!` a lot, then you're probably using the wrong types.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but all I wanted is to variable of type Any could be casted to the type of value it contains. For example in case it contains 5, casting would automatically be Int, without writing Int by user. I guess it’s impossible to do using Swift only, but maybe C or Objective-C?

Comment: You'll need to explain what "casted to the type of value it contains" actually means. Casting is (almost entirely) a static, runtime operation to allow you to make method calls or function calls using the new type. There's no method or function that the compiler can apply to "the type of value it contains." That's not known until runtime. So, if you had what you're asking for, what would you write after `var casted = item as! type(of: item)` that you couldn't write with `item` directly? I'm not certain what you're thinking of when you ask about ObjC and C here.

Comment: I've made some guesses on what might be your underlying problem. Please let me know if your actual problem is something different, and explain it in your question. As asked, the answer is "no, that's impossible." But I'd like to dig into why it's intentionally impossible. This isn't a missing feature. It goes to the heart of any strongly typed language.

Comment: I want to achieve **var casted** as Int using this assignment, so I would do with it the same as usually doing with Integers. But it’s impossible even using function **func cast<T>(_ value: Any, to type: T.Type) -> T { value as! T }** , It simply causes an error. Ok, I understood that type(of:) is useless here because it returns type of var casted which is Any, and “there’s no method or function that the compiler can apply to the type of value it contains”, but maybe ObjC runtime can help?

Comment: `type(of:)` returns Int here since it returns the underlying type **at runtime**. That's not actually the problem. It's just that what you're asking for can't do anything meaningful. There is no line of code you could write after this cast that you couldn't write using Any. Say `cast()` existed and did precisely what you want. What line of code would you write next that used `casted` that couldn't use `item`?

Comment: cast() would return Int if it would did what I want. I tried to use it like **cast(item, to: type(of: item))** , it causes an error.

Comment: What if `item` is not of type Int? It's Any, so it could be anything (a String, a UIViewController, a MyCustomType). Given that, what would the next line of code be after your working version of `cast()` returned? (Again, what you want is impossible, no just in Swift, but in anything with a type system similar to Swift's. Will you tell us what you're going to do with it so we can help you find a solution, or do you just want the answer "this is impossible?")

Comment: @Zeta I would really suggest you take a brief step back and really listen to what Rob is trying to tell you in his answer. It's exactly on-point. There's no workaround, because what you're requesting is essentially time travel. Type systems are static constructs evaluated at compile time. The runtime type of a value is only available at... runtime, obviously. There's no way for that dynamic runtime type information to travel back in time to be available to the compiler during compile time. There's no statically-typed language (ObjC, C, or any other) that could *possibly* work around that.

Answer (score 2):

Considering your first example:

```
var item: Any = 5
var casted = item as! type(of: item)
```

To avoid confusion, let's assume you have an `otherItem` as casting blueprint that provides a concrete type, then yes, you can do it, but you have to use Swift's provided tools for static typing, in this case generics and `.self` to obtain an instance's type.

Here is an example how you could do it (inspired from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38792967)):

```
func cast<T>(value: Any, to type: T) -> T {
    return value as! T
}

let item: Any = "this is a test"
let otherItem: String = "Hello World"
let otherType = otherItem.self // or explicit: String.self()
let casted = cast(value: item, to: otherType)
```

---

Regarding your second question: In order to define an instance of your generic type in the function, the compiler would have to know *how* to initialize it. Therefore it doesn't work with an unconstrained generic type T that provides no information on that. However, there is a way to do it:

- Create a protocol `Initializable` that requires an initializer `init(a:, b:, ...)` (whatever arguments you need)
- Add the protocol as constraint to your function, i.e. `func function<T: Initializable>() -> ...`
- Now, within the function you can call `let x = T.init(a:, b:, ...)` as it is ensured that the type T provides such an initializer.